# Lambda Expression selecting Max Numeric Value from a collection of AlphaNumeric Strings

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I have this below SQL query that selects the Maximum integer value from a varchar field where the values start with MB.

```
select max( cast(substring( sLicenseNo, 4, len(sLicenseNo)) as int)) as licno from ApplicationForm where sLicenseNo like 'MB%'
```

How can I convert this lambda expression for use with entity framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
TestDataContext db = new TestDataContext();
var res = db.ApplicationForms.Where(y => y.sLicenseNo.Contains("MB")).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.sLicenseNo.Substring(2))).Max();
```

Tell me if it works or not.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response, I am getting this exception : "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 ToInt64(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Any ideas ?

Comment: Just do the conversion outside the query by looping through the result and convert each row to int, then you can select the max. Hope this helps